# Возможно ли стирать объекты в Graphics? (c#)

Tags: c#, bitmap, graphics

Здравствуйте!
Есть Bitmap, к которому я привязал графику. Вот нарисовал я, скажем, на этом Bitmap'e круг. Возможно ли его стереть? Или нужно сохранять отрисованные точки в отдельное место и при желании что-то удалить - все перерисовывать?

P.S. - костыль с использованием background'a в качестве основы для текстурной кисти не подходит, ибо у меня bitmap накладывается на картинку, которая в последствии меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Graphics.Clear

```
public void Clear(
    Color color
)
```

Очищает всю поверхность рисования и выполняет заливку поверхности указанным цветом фона.

### Параметры

#### color

- **Type**: System.Drawing.Color
- **Структура**: Color, которая представляет собой цвет фона для поверхности рисования.

### Пример

```
private void ClearColor(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear screen with teal background.
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Teal);
}
```

#### Доступно с .NET Framework 1.1

Comment: То есть, лишь вариант - очистить вообще все? Ладно. Печально, спасибо

Comment: @Kir_Antipov увы, да.